# ListView check-boxes are being checked all at once

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this `ListView.builder` with simple `Cards`, it's build with `bloc` like so:

```
   return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                    var snap = snapshot.data.documents[index];
...
```

inside this list I have `checkbox`s like so:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    bool _isChacked = false;

...

Card(
                                    elevation: 10.0,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 60.0,
                                      height: 50.0,
                                      child: Checkbox(
                                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                                          value: _isChacked,
                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _isChacked = value;
                                              print(value);
                                            });
                                          },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

if I click I get the check-boxes to change value but unfortunately all at onece how do I target everyone on it's own?

I thought about a `List` or a `Map` but I do not know how to use it.

also It's not important to hold the state of the check-boxes because saving the value to a db I know but I just need it locally.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953911/flutter-trouble-with-multiselect-checkboxes-data-from-firestore/56956573#56956573

Comment: it's not a duplicate, I need dynamic checkboxes, and the other question is about simple

Comment: Can you let me know what `dynamic checkboxes` are? Had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956573/4453205?

Answer (score 3):

Because all the checkboxes are depending on the `_isChecked` value. If you only want checkbox can be toggle, you should use

```
    List<int> _selected_box = List();
    ...

    child: Checkbox(
             activeColor: Colors.red,
             value: _selected_box.contains(index),//index is the position of the checkbox
             onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                      // remove or add index to _selected_box
                      if(_selected_box.contains(index)) _selected_box.remove(index);
                      else _selected_box.add(index); 
                      print(index);
                  });
             },
             ),
```